# Incrementing a Number Sequence in a Dynamic Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a procedure called `TableNumberSequence` that adds a table row, pauses for a second and then adds another. It does this up until what's specified in the code, which is `< 9`.

At the moment, the rows are blank. The problem is I don't know how to generate a number sequence from `1` to `8` to populate the rows.

I know how to do this with a `For Each` loop outside a table, but doing it inside one is giving me a headache.

[Number Sequence Loop.xlsb](https://easyupload.io/hlryf3)

```vb
Sub TableNumberSequence()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range
Dim n As Integer

Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

Set rng = tbl.ListColumns("Number").DataBodyRange

Call DeleteAllRows

    n = 1
    
    Do While n < 9
    
    Call IntervalTime

        n = n + 1
        
    Call AddRow
        
    Loop

End Sub
```

These additional procedures are called in the main one.

```vb
Sub AddRow()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

    tbl.ListRows.Add

End Sub

Sub DeleteAllRows()

    With Range("Table1").ListObject
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Sub IntervalTime()
   
   Dim target As Date

   target = Now + TimeValue("00:00:" & Range("Interval").Text)
   
    Do
       DoEvents
    Loop Until Now >= target
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - Here's a full tested version:

```
Sub TableNumberSequence()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim n, sec As Double
    
    sec = Range("Interval").Value 'use a number here
    Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    DeleteAllRows tbl 'remove rows

    For n = 1 To 8
        AddRow tbl, n
        IntervalTime sec
    Next n
End Sub

'add a row and place `id` in the first cell
Sub AddRow(tbl As ListObject, id)
    tbl.ListRows.Add.Range.Cells(1).Value = id
End Sub

'remove any rows from listobject `tbl`
Sub DeleteAllRows(tbl As ListObject)
    If Not tbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then tbl.DataBodyRange.Delete
End Sub

'wait for `sec` seconds
Sub IntervalTime(sec As Double)
    Dim t
    t = Timer
    Do While Timer - t < sec
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: That is leaving an empty row between each number. By the way, the interval number refers to the amount of pause time between each loop — not row gaps.